# Wine1.7 cannot be uninstalled completely

Tags: 13.10, wine

I uninstalled Wine 1.7 by `apt-get remove wine1.7`. But I found the programs I installed in `.wine` can still run. How can I uninstall them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Open a terminal and type the following commands

```
sudo apt-get remove wine --purge
```

Next, we clean the context menu, menu entries, etc:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.wine
rm -f $HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged/*wine*
rm -rf $HOME/.local/share/applications/wine
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/*wine*
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/icons/????_*.xpm
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/icons/*wine*
```

Now restart the system using:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: After I typed"sudo apt-get remove wine --purge"in a terminal,"...is not installed,so not removed"

Comment: I don't think it's sufficient to purge the `wine` package itself, it's just a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages). As for the `rm` commands, that is a solution...to a different problem from the one here. Here, the issue isn't that Wine config or Windows files are present. It's that *the core Wine executable and supporting files* still exist and Wine actually runs! Finally note that `rm` with `-r`/`-R` on a path that starts with `$HOME` or `~`, if entered with *a 1-character typo*, deletes the user's home folder! So a warning (or different way of doing it) is in order.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

sudo ppa-purge ppa:wine/wine-builds
```

Source:

http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-wine-1-9-on-ubuntu/